# How do I batch encode hevc videos using avisynth source?

Tags: batch-processing, video-processing, h.265, handbrake, avisynth

I have several videos I need to process using avisynth then encode to hevc mkv format.

I can use avsproxy and open in avidemux but I can't batch it.  I have a lot of videos that use basically the same script. I can easily create a script for each file but I don't have anything that takes it as an input.

Comment: Check out my [Baka Encoder](http://vtt.to/baka%20encoder). It is capable of batch encoding avisynth scripts with hevc video codec. Muxing into mkv is not yet supported though.

Answer (score 1):

If Windows is an option, you can use [FFASTrans](http://www.ffastrans.com/) - it's automation encoding software, based on AviSynth and FFMpeg.

You can either use built-in modules to process video or your own AVS files as a source of video.

The software is freeware, though is not open sourced.

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest command line call for `ffmpeg`

```
SET ffmpegpath=c:/ffmpeg-win-2.2.2/ffmpeg.exe
%ffmpegpath% -i input.avs -c:v libx265 -f matroska -y output.mkv
```